# ruby remove duplicates and modify existing element in nested array by iterating over another array

Tags: ruby

I have an array **doc_count** that contains string with Date (year-month-day) among other things.

I'd like to transform **doc_count** into **goal** by removing "duplicates" that means, I'd like to keep the longer date-string and remove the short date-string eg.

> "2019-02-01: 186904" instead of "2019-02-01"

```
  doc_count = [
    ["foo", "2019-02-01: 186904", "2019-03-01: 196961", "2019-01-01", "2019-02-01", "2019-03-01", "2019-04-01"],
    ["bar", "2019-01-01: 8876", "2019-04-01: 8694", "2019-01-01", "2019-02-01", "2019-03-01", "2019-04-01"]
  ]

  goal = [
    ["foo", "2019-01-01", "2019-02-01: 186904", "2019-03-01: 196961", "2019-04-01"],
    ["bar", "2019-01-01: 8876", "2019-02-01", "2019-03-01", "2019-04-01: 8694"]
  ]

   month.match(/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/) && month.include?(': ') ? 
     month.match(/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/)[0] : month

  my_attempt = doc_count.each do |topic|
    topic.each do |el|
      topic.delete(el) if el == string_to_month(el)
    end
  end
```

For some reason my attempt fails to generate an array identical to **goals**.

```
  2.6.3 (main):0 > my_attempt       
  => [
    [0] [
      [0] "foo",
      [1] "2019-02-01: 186904",
      [2] "2019-03-01: 196961",
      [3] "2019-02-01",
      [4] "2019-04-01"
    ],
    [1] [
      [0] "bar",
      [1] "2019-01-01: 8876",
      [2] "2019-04-01: 8694",
      [3] "2019-02-01",
      [4] "2019-04-01"
    ]
  ]
```

How can I fix this? Thank you very much!

Comment: What if `"2019-04-01"` occurs before `"2019-04-01: 8694"`? Which one should be removed?

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk string with a colon should always stay in array and the string only with date should be removed. the order in array isn't relevant.

Comment: "the order in array isn't relevant" but example shows, that `goal` "lines" are ordered by complex rule: "foo" at the begin and then by date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
doc_count = [
  ["foo", "2019-02-01: 186904", "2019-03-01: 196961", "2019-01-01", 
   "2019-02-01", "2019-03-01", "2019-04-01"],
  ["bar", "2019-01-01: 8876", "2019-04-01: 8694", "2019-01-01",
   "2019-02-01", "2019-03-01", "2019-04-01"]
]
```

We may write

```
def doit(doc_count)
  doc_count.map do |arr|
    date_strings, other_strings =
      arr.partition { |s| s.match? /\A\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}(?::|\z)/ }
    other_strings + select_dates(date_strings)
  end
end
```

where `select_dates` is a method yet to be constructed.

The calculations for `doc_count[0]` are as follows:

```
arr = doc_count[0]
  #=> ["foo", "2019-02-01: 186904", "2019-03-01: 196961", "2019-01-01",
  #    "2019-02-01", "2019-03-01", "2019-04-01"] 
date_strings, other_strings =
  arr.partition { |s| s.match? /\A\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}(?::|\z)/ }
  #=> [["2019-02-01: 186904", "2019-03-01: 196961", "2019-01-01",
  #     "2019-02-01", "2019-03-01", "2019-04-01"], ["foo"]] 
date_strings
  #=> ["2019-02-01: 186904", "2019-03-01: 196961", "2019-01-01",
  #    "2019-02-01", "2019-03-01", "2019-04-01"] 
other_strings
  #=> ["foo"]
```

The calculations for the second element of `doc_count` are similar. See [Enumerable#partition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition).

I will now give two ways to construct the method `select_dates`, the first being the more efficient, the second arguably the more straightforward.

**Use the form of [Hash#update](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0.preview1/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged**

```
def select_dates(date_strings)
  date_strings.each_with_object({}) do |s,h|
    h.update(s[0, 10]=>s) { |_,o,n| n.size >= o.size ? n : o }
  end.values
end
```

See the doc for explanations of the block variables `_`, `o` and `n` (`_`--a valid local variable--is used for the first block variable to tell the reader that it is not used in the block calculation). For `date_strings` given above for `doc_count[0]`

```
select_dates(date_strings)
  #=> ["2019-02-01: 186904", "2019-03-01: 196961", "2019-01-01",
  #    "2019-04-01"]
```

The calculations are as follows.

```
 enum = date_strings.each_with_object({})
   #=> #<Enumerator: ["2019-02-01: 186904", "2019-03-01: 196961",
   #   "2019-01-01", "2019-02-01", "2019-03-01", "2019-04-01"
   #                 ]:each_with_object({})>
```

```
 s,h = enum.next
   #=> ["2019-02-01: 186904", {}] 
 s #=> "2019-02-01: 186904" 
 h #=> {} 
 key = s[0, 10]
   #=> "2019-02-01" 
 h.update(key=>s) { |_,o,n| n.size >= o.size ? n : o }
   #=> {"2019-02-01"=>"2019-02-01: 186904"}
```

```
 s,h = enum.next
   #=> ["2019-03-01: 196961", {"2019-02-01"=>"2019-02-01: 186904"}] 
 key = s[0, 10]
   #=> "2019-03-01" 
 h.update(key=>s) { |_,o,n| n.size >= o.size ? n : o }
   #=> {"2019-02-01"=>"2019-02-01: 186904",
   #    "2019-03-01"=>"2019-03-01: 196961"}
```

```
 s,h = enum.next
   #=> ["2019-01-01", {"2019-02-01"=>"2019-02-01: 186904",
   #    "2019-03-01"=>"2019-03-01: 196961"}] 
 key = s[0, 10]
   #=> "2019-01-01" 
 h.update(key=>s) { |_,o,n| n.size >= o.size ? n : o }
   #=> {"2019-02-01"=>"2019-02-01: 186904",
   #    "2019-03-01"=>"2019-03-01: 196961", "2019-01-01"=>"2019-01-01"}
```

```
 s,h = enum.next
   #=> ["2019-02-01", {"2019-02-01"=>"2019-02-01: 186904",
   #    "2019-03-01"=>"2019-03-01: 196961", "2019-01-01"=>"2019-01-01"}] 
 key = s[0, 10]
   #=> "2019-02-01" 
 h.update(key=>s) { |_,o,n| n.size >= o.size ? n : o }
   #=> {"2019-02-01"=>"2019-02-01: 186904",
   #    "2019-03-01"=>"2019-03-01: 196961", "2019-01-01"=>"2019-01-01"}
```

For the first three elements of `enum` that are generated and passed to the block, `update`'s block does not come into play, as the two hashes being merged (`h` and `{ key=>s }`) do not have a common key. For the fourth element `("2019-02-01")`, which is present in both hashes being merged, we defer to the block to compare `h["2019-02-01"].size #=> "2019-02-01: 186904".size => 18` with `"2019-02-01".size #=> 10`. Since the former is larger we keep it as the value of `"2019-02-01"` in `h`. The remaining calculations for `update` are similar, resulting in:

```
h #=>  ["2019-02-01"=>"2019-02-01: 186904",
  #     "2019-03-01"=>"2019-03-01: 196961", "2019-01-01"=>"2019-01-01",
  #     "2019-04-01"=>"2019-04-01" }
```

The final step is to extract the values from this hash (`h.values`).

**Use [Array#uniq](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq)**

```
def select_dates(date_strings)
  date_strings.sort_by(&:size).reverse.uniq { |s| s[0, 10] }
end
```

For `date_strings` given above for `doc_count[0]`

```
select_dates(date_strings)
  #=> ["2019-03-01: 196961", "2019-02-01: 186904", "2019-04-01",
  #    "2019-01-01"]
```

The calculations are as follows.

```
a = date_strings.sort_by(&:size)
  #=> ["2019-01-01", "2019-02-01", "2019-03-01", "2019-04-01",
  #    "2019-02-01: 186904", "2019-03-01: 196961"] 
b = a.reverse
  #=> ["2019-03-01: 196961", "2019-02-01: 186904", "2019-04-01",
  #    "2019-03-01", "2019-02-01", "2019-01-01"] 
b.uniq { |s| s[0, 10] }
  #=> ["2019-03-01: 196961", "2019-02-01: 186904", "2019-04-01",
  #    "2019-01-01"]
```

Note that the doc for `Array#uniq` states, "`self` is traversed in order, and the first occurrence is kept.". The expression

```
sort_by(&:size).reverse
```

could be replaced by

```
sort_by { |s| -s.size }
```

but it has been reported that what I've used tends to be faster.

Answer (score 2):

One solution could be a combination of [Array#flat_map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) und [#max_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by)

method #flat_map returns a new array with the concatenated results of running block once for every element and #max_by an array of maximum elements. You already used #match to check for date-format but in this example there's no need to move it in a separate method.

```
solution = doc_count.map do |topic|
  topic.group_by { |s| s[0..9] }.flat_map do 
    |key, values| key.match?(/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/) ? [values.max_by(&:size)] : values 
  end.sort.rotate!(-1)
end
```

last but not least #sort and #rotate(-1) to get the desired sort order of the array.

UPDATE: please use Cary Swoveland's solution, it's better and he did an extraordinary job to explain the steps in detail.

Comment: Perhaps neither better nor worse, but consider first separating the dates from the non-dates, then `non_dates + dates.group_by(&:size).values.map { |a| a.max_by(&:size) }`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes, good point! Emily Did you see Cary Swovelands solution? Consider changing the accepted answer from mine to Cary Swoveland's. I'd prefer his solution and he did an extraordinary job explaining all the necessary steps in detail.

Comment: I just changed the accepted answer to Cary Swoveland's solution even though I keep using your solution, it's much shorter and does the trick.